# How to count how many times a meta_value appears in a column by certain meta_key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to query how many times each record exists on a column in my table from database in WordPress and export that column. How would I do this?

In the excel exported I want to have the column from meta_value with meta_key "user_valid" and a column with the count of how many times that meta_value exists in the mysql column.

```
meta_key          meta_value

user_valid        '1, 2, 3'      
user_valid        '1, 2, 1' 
user_valid        '1, 2, 3'
```

For exporting the column 'meta_value' with the meta_key 'user_valid' I used:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `us_test` WHERE meta_key = 'user_valid'
```

And I export with the export button from MYSQL after using this query.

I don't know how to do the query for the other column.

I think it should be something like this but I'm not sure, because when I use the next query it doesn't return all the records:

```
SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) c FROM `us_test` WHERE meta_key = 'user_valid' GROUP BY meta_value
```

Comment: I'm confused...are you giving yourself bounty for an "exemplary" answer? Or are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: @rnevius I think OP chose the wrong bounty explanation. There are better ways to do this, so I think he needs answers with these alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I will answer my own question:

The query from my question is absolutely correct:

```
SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) c FROM `us_test` WHERE meta_key = 'user_valid' GROUP BY meta_value
```

Answer (score 10):

You have two options here, the Wordpress way and the other way, SQL.

Just before I start, you should never ever hardcode a db name, the issue is, you would need to change the db name in all queries where it is hardcode should you move the code to another website with a different db name, also when you change the db name on the site you are working on. This can set you on a wild goose chase should you forget about that

You should  **always always sanitize and validate input data** to ensure it is safe to prevent any malicious code being injected into your site. SQL injection is common and many hackers use SQL injection to hack a site

### SQL

SQL gives one a bit less control as it is less dynamic. For instance, if you need get a count for a certain term only, you would need to alter the query directly or you will need to implement some kind of filter system.

As I have stated, never ever hardcode db names, rather use the wpdb class to set the prefix. This will avoid issues going forward. Also, as I said, you have to sanitize to avoid SQL injection, in this case, we will use the `prepare` method of the wpdb class to take care of sanitation and will safeguard against SQL injection.

Here is the function, which I have commented here and there to make sense:

```
function get_post_meta_key_count( $key = '', $value = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) 
{
    // Use $wpdb to avoid bugs and errors, do not hardcode db names
    global $wpdb;

    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;


    // Set the default WHERE clause where we return the count of the key regardless of value
    $where = $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            pm.meta_key = '%s' 
            AND p.post_type = '%s' 
            AND p.post_status = '%s'
        ", 
        $key, 
        $type, 
        $status 
    );

    // If a value is specified, add that to the WHERE clause
    if ( $value ) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( 
            "
                AND pm.meta_value = '%s'
            ", 
            $value 
        );
    }

    // Query the db to return the post count according to key and value if value is set
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        "
            SELECT count(DISTINCT pm.post_id)
            FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
            WHERE {$where}
        "
    );

    return $count;
}
```

What I have done here is, I have set a parameter if you ever need to get the count of a specific meta value of a specific meta key.

**USAGE**

You can now use the function as follow:

- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key' );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key` for the default post type `post` and only published posts
- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key', '', 'custom_post_type', 'trash' );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key` for the custom post type `custom_post_type` and only trashed posts
- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key', 'my_value' );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key`  and for the `meta_value`, `my_value` for the default post type `post` and only published posts

### `WP_Query`

If you are looking for a build in way to do this (*which should always be your first option*), you can use the `WP_Query` class to do it.

The issue with using `WP_Query` is that, it can be really expensive if not used correctly. Many people avoid `WP_Query` because of this, or unknowingly runs queries that are quite expensive and unnecessary. So will look at a way to make this as fast as a custom SQL query.

The real advantage of `WP_Query` above a custom SQL query is, you can adjust the query by simply passing in the parameters needed, `WP_Query` will always take care of the hard work to construct the proper SQL query according to the passed parameters.

Lets look at optimizing `WP_Query` in order to just return a post count

- Firstly, we will only query one single post. `WP_Query`, by default, is build such that no matter how many posts are queried (*1, 100 or all posts*), `WP_Query` will continue to look for **all** posts matching the query, even though it has already found and returned the queried amount of posts. The reason for this is pagination. In order to correctly calculate pagination, `WP_Query` needs to know how many posts are there which matches the query.

  So `WP_Query` continues to look through the db after returning the amount of posts queried in order to count all posts that matches the query. This post count is stored in the `$found_posts` property of the query, and it is this number that is used in conjunction with `posts_per_page` which is used to calculate how many pages there would be.

  This does not work for `get_posts`, although `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`. `get_posts` passes `'no_found_rows' => true` to `WP_Query` which breaks the query as soon as the amount of queried posts are found. This legally breaks pagination, that is why `get_posts` are such a huge headache to paginate correctly
- Secondly, we will only query the single post's ID we need to query, not the complete `WP_Post` object. This saves on query time.

So lets look at this function:

```
function get_post_meta_key_count( $key = '', $value = '', $args = [] ) 
{
    // If the $key value is empty, bail
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;

    // Set the defaults and override any value set for the specific default
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    $args['fields']         = 'ids';

    if ( $value ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = [
            'key'   => $key,
            'value' => $value
        ];
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'][] = [
            'key' => $key,
        ];
    }
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Return the post count
    return $q->found_posts;
}
```

**USAGE**

`WP_Query`, by default, uses the `post` post type and `publish` as post status, so we do not need to set this for normal published posts. I have included a third parameter here called `$args`, this parameter accepts the same exact parameters as the `WP_Query` class as these are all passed directly to `WP_Query`. So you can add any parameters here to get a count from from a specific meta key or value

- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key' );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key` for the default post type `post` and only published posts
- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key', 'my_value' );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key`  and for the `meta_value`, `my_value` for the default post type `post` and only published posts
- `echo get_post_meta_key_count( 'my_key', 'my_value', ['post_type'=>'cpt', 'cat'=>1] );` for post count of `meta_key` `my_key`  and for the `meta_value`, `my_value` for the custom post type `cpt` and only published posts from the category ID `1`

### PERFORMANCE TESTING ON `meta_key` with 24 posts

- **SQL** -> 1 query in +/- 0.005 seconds
- **`WP_Query`** -> 2 queries in +/- 0.012 seconds

As you can see, there is a minute difference in performance, so the `WP_Query` method will easily be the best option here as it is much more dynamic, even though just a tad slower